# Mysql big table with datetime column

Tags: mysql

What is the best thing for my scenario

I have a tables with nearly 20,000,000 records, which basically stores what users have done in the site

- `id` -> primary int 11 auto increment
- `user_id` -> index int 11 not null
- `create_date` -> ( no index yet ) date-time not null
- it has other columns but seems irrelevant to name them here

I know I must put an index on create_date but do I put a single column index or a double column, which one first on the double index ( given the large number of records)?

by the way the query that I'm now using is like :

```
select max(id) -- in here I'm selecting actions that users have done, after this date, since date is today
from table t
where 
    t.create_date >= '2014-12-29 00:00:00'
group by t.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you edit your question with an EXPLAIN PLAN of your SELECT? [EXPLAIN Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html). Meanwhile, you can try with this:

- Make partitions using your date field create_date. [Partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html)
- Build your index with the most restrictive criteria first. I think that in your case, it will be better create_date + user_id

  CREATE INDEX index_name
  ON table_name ( create_date , user_id );